# Ember application fails to load after upgrading it from Ember 2.7 to 2.8 when connected to VPN

Tags: ember.js

Unable to run Ember application locally after upgrading to Ember 2.8 when on VPN.
While disconnected off from VPN, it just works fine.

Trying to start the ember server when connected to VPN gives the below error.

```
bin/ember s
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.63.95.98:4200
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
```

Steps taken/followed -

a. Updated package.json to use Ember 2.8 -

```
"ember-cli": “2.8.0"
```

b. Then ran the below commands from inside the application

```
bower install
npm install
```

c. Also tried clean install for Ember-

i. Begin by uninstalling the old ember-cli:

```
$ npm uninstall –g ember-cli
```

ii. Clear the npm cache:

```
$ npm cache clean
```

iii. Clear the Bower cache:

```
$ bower cache clean
```

iv. Install Ember

```
$ npm install –g ember-cli@2.8.0
```

Ember version -

```
ember -v
ember-cli: 2.8.0
node: 6.8.1
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: The question is not providing the relevant info to diagnose the problem. Things like steps taken for the upgrade or dev console errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is because portfinder >= 1.0.8 is broken. Use 1.0.7 or lower.

Run -

```
npm ls
```

This command will print to stdout all the versions of packages that are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure.

This will output -

```
│ ├─┬ portfinder@1.0.8
│ │ └── async@1.5.2
```

Here's [a link to the issue](https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder/issues/43)!

Resolution -

Add the below line to package.json.

```
"portfinder": "1.0.7"
```

Then, run the below command.

```
rm -rf node_modules/portfinder && npm install
```